# Fetch data from one collection and post to another collection of mongodb using reactjs

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb

In my program data being fetched from  mongodb in every three seconds and display.  When i press a button that time data need to store in  another collection of db

Is it possible in reactjs

Comment: are you using a rest end point to fetch data from the database.  to persist more/other data from the react app you need to handle the client event and post the data to another end point / api that can persist it.

Comment: Yes... But is to possible to create different collections in mongodb. One for get and one for post